# How to optimize a given eigen value metric from a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, convex-optimization

Consider a 3 x 3 matrix A for this example

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Let's assume,in general, that the $$\lambda_i, i\in \text{[0,1,2,3..,n]}$$ are the Eigen-values, if the matrix is of size {n x n}

I want to maximize the sum of all these eigenvalues $$\max\text[\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i]$$

Following conditions are to be met:
1. Only values which are 0 can be changed, values which are 1 remain fixed
2. Only specific discrete changes are allowed, that is 
$$a_{ij}=[-1,0,1], \text{where i=rows and j=column}$$

There are works which discuss optimization problem related to second smallest eigen values https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S000510981830308X
But this work goes beyond my ability to understand. Besides there is another question is StackExchange [linked here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/144886/fast-algorithm-for-maximizing-smallest-eigenvalue-of-linear-combination-of-hermi) that talks about the similar query but it doesn't talk about constraints and also it is talking about the linear sum of matrices.

So how do I address this problem? Any help, please.

P.S Please, if you think my question is wrong and not reasonable then kindly explain to me the reason and I will remove it. Please don't downvote otherwise I won't be able to ask questions in the future as this is first one.

Comment: Don't be worried about your question being downvoted. A question ban only occurs if you have multiple low-quality questions. Downvoting is just a way to say this post does not show any research effort, or that it is unclear or not useful. Even if your question has been closed, you still have a chance to edit the question and ask for it to be reopened (there is a special thread on Math Meta SE for this).

Comment: The sum of the eigenvalues is equal to the trace of the matrix. so try to optimize the trace ...

Comment: I did not put my previous comment as a answer, as the title of your post is more general: *... a metric ...*

Comment: The real problem comes in putting the constraints. Any suggestions on that?

Answer (score 0):

this is more of a comment, which I am not yet allowed to make, so here it is:

You might want to consider [Boyd's lecture](http://web.stanford.edu/class/ee364a/lectures.html). In the 4th lecture, he is talking about *Minimizing spectral radius of nonnegative matrix*, which is a geometric program:

$$ \text{maximize } λ$$
$$ \text{subject to } \sum_{j=1}^n A(x)_{ij}v_j/(λv_i) \leq 1, \forall i = 1, . . . , n$$

which I hope is the same problem or at least similar and it gives you ideas.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am going through it. They do have an example of Bacterial growth over a period of time to make it more understandable.